# Access objects by placing arrow operator in a string

Tags: php

I want to access a property in an object by using `$response->audit->id`. I have placed `audit->id` in a variable and acessed it as `$response->$str` but PHP is escaping the html into `&gt`. I get the following exception.

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$audit-&gt;->id
```

I've tried `htmlspecialchars_decode` and `html_entity_decode` but in vain.

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Comment: No matter who escaped what (PHP didn't), you cannot have an object or array expression in a string variable and expect varvars to resolve them.

Comment: A good approach is to use dot notation and a library like Symfony PropertyAccess

Comment: PHP has dot notation? @rogeriolino

Comment: You probably are looking for something like http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php and possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760622/accessing-object-properties-drilling-down-without-array-conversion/20760687?noredirect=1#comment31113530_20760687. I'm with @mario, PHP ain't escaped nothing unless you told it to or use external code that does.

Comment: No @Derek, using dot notation as string value. Then parse it using ProcessAccess. Ex: `$str = 'audit.id'; $accessor->getValue($response, $str);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594358/how-can-i-access-a-deep-object-property-named-as-a-variable-dot-notation-in-ph/41595663#41595663